# Which event to use to modify server controls when GridView Page changes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm implementing filters that on `Page_PreRender` check which rows meet the criteria that I set.

```
  Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Session("Hotel") <> "Todos" Then
        CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Hotel")
    End If
    If Session("Departamento") <> "Todos" Then
        CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Departamento")
    End If
    If Session("Estado") <> "Todos" And Session("Estado") <> "" Then
        CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(7).FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Estado")
    End If
       ApplyFilters()
  End Sub
```

The filters are saved in session variables (on `DropDownList`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` which cause a postback), I then get (as seen above) and set whichever field they're correspondent to, to whatever they were before the postback. After this is done, the filters are re-applied by calling `ApplyFilters()`.

In case you're wondering how the filters work:

```
 For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If CType(Row.Cells(3).FindControl("Label3"), Label).Text <> Filtro Then
                Row.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
```

Everything seems to work fine until I switch to another `GridView` page, the filters aren't re-applied and all their correspondent `DropDownList`s' values are set to the default value. After refreshing the page everything's back to normal. It seems that changing pages doesn't trigger `Page_PreRender`.
Where should I implement my filters in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to another page in a `GridView` won't trigger `Page_PreRender` so if you want to edit the `GridView`'s content for filtering use `GridView_PreRender`.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.PreRender
        If Session("Hotel") <> "Todos" Then
            CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Hotel")
        End If
        If Session("Departamento") <> "Todos" Then
            CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Departamento")
        End If
        If Session("Estado") <> "Todos" Then
            CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(7).FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList).SelectedValue = Session("Estado")
        End If
        ApplyFilters()
    End Sub
```